# Best way to create user personas?

Tags: personas

What is the best way to create user personas? Is it better practice to write it down on paper or type it on a program?

Comment: Legos - http://jon-walmsley.com/lego-personas/

Comment: Are you asking how to create persona [which is a question abot user research], or how to produce persona descriptions [the physical artefacts used to communicate the persona research]?

Comment: This is like asking what the best way to create a car model is. Clay? CAD? Life size?  Without some information on what you are using the persona for, this is a question that cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "best way", but I can offer a method which appears very often in Persona training: sticky notes.

- Write all your characteristics on sticky notes
- Stick them on the wall in front of all of your other stakeholders
- Argue with everyone as you construct Personas by moving said sticky notes around
- Wait for everyone to go to lunch, make some final changes, confirm the Personas and burn the evidence so no-one can argue.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with everyone else - there really isn't a best way to create personas. I don't think it really matters how you make it (pen and paper or digitally) - it's the data and information you put on it from your research that is important. As long as the persona gives you a better understanding on who you are designing for and what their needs are, then you are doing it right.

There are plenty of tutorials and articles about creating personas but here's just a couple I found:

http://blog.usabilitytools.com/how-to-create-ux-personas/

http://www.ux-lady.com/introduction-to-user-personas/